# Objective c:Asynchronously update UIView with device orientation

Tags: objective-c, uiview, asynchronous

I am facing problem updating UIView asynchronously with device orientation in place. I have implemented device orientation in viewDidload as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[self initialize];}
```

In orientationChanged method, I have following code

```
-(void)orientationChanged {
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)){
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ConsoleViewControllerLandscape" bundle:nil];
    UIView *portraitView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = portraitView;

    [self initialize];

} else {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ConsoleViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView *portraitView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.view = portraitView;

    [self initialize];

}
```

In initialize method, I actually update UI asynchronously with codes like

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(arrangeAsynchronously) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
- (void) arrangeAsynchronously{
    //Some complex calculation and finally
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
}
```

The problem is when orientation changed imageViews are not added to main view. Lets say I am starting with portrait view then I can see all imageviews in portrait view and if it changed to landscape, then view is blank. Again if I switched to portrait, then all subviews i.e. imageViews are properly added. The problem is when orientation changed, I am loading a new nib file however the code still refers to old view loaded from old nob file. How can I change reference. This problem only occurs when I do in asynchronous mode.

Its not problem with uiview rather its with calculation of subview positions after device rotation. Earlier my code was

```
CGAffineTransform inverseTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(self.view.transform);
fixedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(fixedPoint,inverseTransform);
fixedPoint = CGPointMake(fixedPoint.x+126, fixedPoint.y-109);
```

And I changed it to

```
fixedPoint = CGPointMake(fixedPoint.x+126, fixedPoint.y-109);
```

But still I am clueless why affinetransform does not work waitUntilDone:NO and works in waitUntilDone:YES.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is a bit problematic. `self.view` is presented somehow, and just because you make a new `UIView`, doesn't mean it's get replaced in the presented window.

I suggest that you have a container view added to your main `UIView` (the one you replace here), and then change the content of the container view when device orientation is changed.

**EDIT**

My answer might seem a bit unclear so let me try to explain it more detailed.
the `UIView` of a `UIViewController` is presented by a `UIWindow`. It means that the window has a reference to the view. When you change the `UIView` of a `UIViewController` (by constructing a new `UIView`) it does NOT mean that it will reflect in the `UIWindow`.

---

Initial scenario:

*UIViewController->**UIView1**<-UIWindow*

After you construct a new UIView:

*UIViewController->**UIView2**

 UIWindow->**UIView1***

---

As you can see on the above figure, you don't gen any errors, but you now have two views, and changes made in your `UIViewController` does not reflect on the screen.

You might be so lucky that it works the first time however: If you reconstruct the `UIView`  BEFORE it is presented by the UIWindow everything still works, but it is still a bad design, that might easily break (like you are seeing after the timing is changed).

This is the case where things might actually work:

---

Initial scenario:

*UIViewController->**UIView1**

After you construct a new UIView:

*UIViewController->**UIView2**

the window present the view on screen:

*UIViewController->**UIView2**<-UIWindow*

---

Basically you should NEVER throw away your handle to the `UIView` of a `UIViewController` after it has been presented.

I hope this helps on your understanding of how referencing/pointers works.

Comment: easy now cool coder. I'm trying to help you. Let me try to explain a bit more detailed what I see as a problem with your design; You have a view in your viewcontroller that you reconstruct every time the phone is tilted. But somewhere you have a UIWindow or a another viewcontroller that STILL has a reference to that first view. It means that even though you construct a new view you don't get it presented. Basically: you should never reconstruct a UIViewController's view after is has been presented.  I hope this clarify it a bit, -also please try to keep a nice and friendly tone.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, what I am trying to explain is  , the problem occurs when I update view using [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(arrangeAsynchronously) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; but the problem does not come up when waitUntilDone:YES. That means, the problem is not because of View presentation rather it has to do with threading. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: The difference between waitUntilDone YES/NO in your perform selector is when the code will be executed, not the thread performing the operation. Please try the solution I suggest. If that doesn't help, we can discuss the next step.